# Rewriting a URL with RegEx

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have a RegEx problem. Consider the following URL:

http://ab.cdefgh.com/aa-BB/index.aspx

I need a regular expression that looks at "aa-BB" and, if it doesn't
match a number of **specific** values, say:

```
rr-GG
vv-VV
yy-YY
zz-ZZ
```

then the URL should redirect to some place. For example:
http://ab.cdefgh.com/notfound.aspx

In web.config I have urlrewrite rules. I need to know what 
the regex would be between the  tags.

```
 <urlrewrites>
      <rule>
        <url>?</url>
        <rewrite>http://ab.cdefgh.com/notfound.aspx</rewrite>
      </rule>
 </urlrewrites>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the potential for the replacement pattern to be in the domain name or some other level of the directory structure, this should select on the pattern you're interested in:

```
http:\/\/ab\.cdefgh\.com\/(?:aa\-BB|rr\-GG|vv\-VV|yy\-YY|zz\-ZZ)\/index\.aspx
```

where the aa-BB, etc. patterns are simply "or"ed together using the `|` operator.

To further break this apart, all of the `/`, `.`, and `-` characters need to be escaped with a `\` to prevent the regex from interpreting them as syntax.  The `(?:` notation means to group the things being "or"ed without storing it in a backreference variable (this makes it more efficient if you don't care about retaining the value selected).

Here is a link to a demonstration (maybe this can help you play around with the regex here to get to exactly which character combinations you want)

http://rubular.com/r/UfB65UyYrj

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
^([a-z])\1-([A-Z])\2.*
```

It matches:

```
uu-FF/
aa-BB/
bb-CC/index
```

But not

```
aaBB
asdf
ba-BB
aA-BB
```

---

*(Edit based on comment)*

Just pipe delimit your desired urls inside of () and escaping special chars.

Eg.

```
^(xx-YY|yy-ZZ|aa-BB|goodStuff)/.*
```

---

But, I think you might actually want the following which matches anything other than the urls that you specify, so that all else goes to notfound.aspx:

```
^[^(xx-YY|yy-ZZ|aa-BB|goodStuff)]/.*
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob. No that is good. But I need it to only match a limited number of those values, not just lower-UPPER but, specifically, xx-XX, yy-YY, zz-ZZ (for example) and everything else (ie aa-AA, bb-BB, cc-CC, and so on) will not match and cause the redirect to the not found url.

Comment: Thanks again Jacob. Sorry, I am really not a regex guy. how do I make sure the full URL gets evaluated and the expression "HERE" is where the regex happens. such as: http://ab.cdefgh.com/HERE/index.aspx

Comment: The first "^" means the start of the URI (the part that comes after the first /) The next part is the [^(don'tmatchthis|orthis|orthisone)] is the next part of the match. The "^" in the [] means don't match the stuff in there. Finally the "/.*" meands a "/" followed by any number of chars.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want anything but xx-XX, yy-YY and zz-ZZ to redirect:

```
[^(xx\-XX)|(yy\-YY)|(zz\-ZZ)]
```